# Cordova Android . Web sql database erased while update on market

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, web-sql

I got a very annoing issue. I've publish an android application (using **cordova**) on android market and the problem is when I publish an update the **web sql** database are erased and user lose all there data.
I try to update it manually on my test device the data stay but each time i do it on the market it don't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe use some sort of "ALTER TABLE" if exists?

Comment: I only do : tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');    So after the application update the table should exist and don't be erased.

Comment: Has the database schema been changed or have you used changeVersion anywhere? Between when the app was release and the update.

Answer (score 0):

No the changeVersion do not change between release.

I've change cordova version from 2.3 to 2.4 it solves the problem ... But i'm not sure cordova has any influence on websql on android neither the 2.3 contain such a bug ...
My yesterday release worked well, i'll keep on investigate on this very annoying issue. Thank you